# Merge $lookup result into existing document array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

-room collection

```
 _id: ObjectId("xxx")
 bedspaces: Array
  0:ObjectId("xx")
  1:ObjectId("xx")
 ***
 ***
```

-bedspace collection

```
_id: ObjectId("xxxx");
number: 1
decks: Array
{
 _id: ObjectId("xxx");
 number: 1
 status: "Vacant"
 tenant: ObjectId("5c964ae7f5097e3020d1926c")
 dueRent: 11
 away: null
},
{
 _id: ObjectId("xxx");
 number: 2
 status: "Vacant"
 tenant: null
 dueRent: 11
 away: null
}
```

Under the decks array, is my tenant field, that have objectId, and i am going to lookup this object id, in the tenants, collection.

-tenant collection

```
 _id: ObjectId("5c964ae7f5097e3020d1926c");
name: 'John Doe'
```

-expected output

```
/*room collection*/
_id: ObjectId("xxx")
bedspaces: [
  {
    _id: ObjectId("xxx")
    number: 1
    decks: [
      {
        _id: ObjectId("xxx")
        number: 1
        status: "Vacant"
        tenant: {
         name: 'John Doe'
        }
        dueRent: 11
        away: null
      },
      {
        _id: ObjectId("xxx");
        number: 1
        status: "Vacant"
        tenant: null
        dueRent: 11
        away: null
      }
    ]
  }
  ]
```

There is also an instances, that deck array is equal to null.

In below aggregation it will only display the decks, that have tenant with object id, what i want is to display both the decks.

```
   {
  from: 'beds',
  let: {bedspace: '$bedspaces'},
  pipeline:[
    {
      $match: {
        $expr: {
          $in: ["$_id", "$$bedspace"]
        }
      }
    },
    {
       $unwind: "$decks"
    },
  {
  $lookup: {
    from: 'tenants',
    let: {tenant: "$decks.tenant"},
    pipeline: [
    {
      $match: {
        $expr: {
          $eq: ["$_id", "$$tenant"]
        }
      } 


 }
    ],
    as: "decks.tenant",
  }
},
{
  $unwind: "$decks.tenant"
},
 { $group: {
        _id: "$_id",
        decks: { $push: "$decks" },
        number: {$first: "$number"}
      }}

  ],
  as: "bedspaces"
}
```

"how can i add condition on my second look up, to execute only if tenant is not null", so that i could retrieve both decks, or any work-around so i could achieved my desired result

Comment: No there is not any such condition but it is very unclear what you expect unless you can show some data capable of producing an expected result and showing the expected result obtainable from that data. Most likely your issue here is the `$unwind` since `$lookup` returns an empty array when nothing is matched. But that's just an educated guess without seeing some data in order to reproduce the problem or the expected result from.

Comment: @NeilLunn can you suggest a work around, so i could achieve my desired result??

Comment: I can if you actually supply some data. A screenshot is not data people can work with. The documents can be viewed in a text representation, so please include the content that is "text" in your question and not pictures. We can actually copy and paste text. The best way to see the text representation of the documents is to use the `mongo` shell that is installed with your MongoDB installation. Also please read what I said, and it does not escape notice that the code in the question basically comes from an answer from someone else and we really would be expecting some effort applied.

Comment: @NeilLunn after hours of trying, haven't got the desired result, i hope can you help me out on this one. I have updated my query above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Don't really have time for all the explanation right now (sorry)</s>,

## Explanation

The basic issue here is that usage of [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) is your problem and you don't need it. Use [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) on the produced array content merging with the `"decks"` array instead. Then you can have `nulls`.

What you want to do here is have the values from the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) from your `"tenants"` collection *transposed* into the existing array within your `"beds/bedspaces"` collection for it's own existing `"tenant"` values which are the `ObjectId` references for the foreign collection.

The [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) stage cannot do this by simply naming the field path within the `"as"` output where that path is already inside another array, and in fact the output of [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) is *always* an array of results obtained from the foreign collection. You want *singular* values for each actual match, and of course you expect a `null` to be in place where nothing matches, and of course keeping the original document array of `"decks"` intact, but just including the foreign details where those were found.

Your code attempt seems *partially* aware of this point as you are using [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) on the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) result on the `""tenants"` collection into a *"temporary array"* ( but you put in in the existing path and that overwrites content ) and then attempting to "re-group" as an array through [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/). But the problem of course is the `$lookup` result does not apply to **every** array member within `"decks"`, so you end up with less results than you want.

The real solution is not a *"conditional [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)"*, but instead to *transpose* the *"temporary array"* content from the result into the existing `"decks"` entries. You do this using [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) to process the array members, and [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) along with [`$indexOfArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/) in order to return the matching elements from the *"temporary array"* by the matching `_id` values to `"tenant"`.

```
          { "$lookup": {
            "from": Tenant.collection.name,
            "let": { "tenant": "$decks.tenant" },
            "pipeline": [
              { "$match": {
                "$expr": { "$in": [ "$_id", "$$tenant" ] }
              }}
            ],
            "as": "tenant"
          }},
          { "$addFields": {
            "decks": {
              "$map": {
                "input": "$decks",
                "in": {
                  "$mergeObjects": [
                    "$$this",
                    {
                      "tenant": {
                        "$cond": {
                          "if": {
                            "$eq": [
                              { "$indexOfArray": ["$tenant._id", "$$this.tenant"] },
                              -1
                            ]
                          },
                          "then": null,
                          "else": {

                            "$arrayElemAt": [
                              "$tenant",
                              { "$indexOfArray": ["$tenant._id", "$$this.tenant"]}
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
```

Noting there we are using [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) inside the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) in order to keep the existing content of the `"decks"` array and only replace ( or "merge" ) an overwritten representation of `"tenant"` for each array member. You are using the expressive [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) already and this like [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/) is a MongoDB 3.6 feature.

Just for interest the same thing can be done by just specifying every field within the array. i.e:

```
            "decks": {
              "$map": {
                "input": "$decks",
                 "in": {
                   "_id": "$$this._id",
                   "number": "$$this.number",
                   "tenant": {
                     // same expression
                   },
                   "__v": "$$this.__v"     // just because it's mongoose
                 }
               }
             }
```

Much the same can be said for the `$$REMOVE` used in the [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) which is also another MongoDB 3.6 feature. You can alternately just use [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and simply omit the unwanted fields:

```
{ "$project": {
  "number": "$number",
  "decks": {
    "$map": { /* same expression */ }
  },
  "__v": "$__v"
  // note we don't use the "tenant" temporary array
}}
```

But that's basically how it works. By taking the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) result and then *transposing* those results back into the original array within the document.

## Example Listing

Also abstracting on your data from previous questions here, which is a bit better than what you posted in the question here. Runnable listing for demonstration:

```
const { Schema, Types: { ObjectId } } = mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/hotel';
const opts = { useNewUrlParser: true };

mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);
mongoose.set('useCreateIndexes', true);
mongoose.set('debug', true);

const tenantSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  age: Number
});

const deckSchema = new Schema({
  number: Number,
  tenant: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Tenant' }
});

const bedSchema = new Schema({
  number: Number,
  decks: [deckSchema]
});

const roomSchema = new Schema({
  bedspaces: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Bed' }]
});


const Tenant = mongoose.model('Tenant', tenantSchema);
const Bed = mongoose.model('Bed', bedSchema);
const Room = mongoose.model('Room', roomSchema);

const log = data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2));

(async function() {

  try {

    const conn = await mongoose.connect(uri, opts);

    // Clean data
    await Promise.all(
      Object.entries(conn.models).map(([k, m]) => m.deleteMany())
    );

    // Insert data
    let [john, jane, bilbo ] = await Tenant.insertMany([
      {
        _id: ObjectId("5c964ae7f5097e3020d1926c"),
        name: "john doe",
        age: 11
      },
      {
        _id: ObjectId("5c964b2531bc162fdce64f15"),
        name: "jane doe",
        age: 12
      },
      {
        _id: ObjectId("5caa5454494558d863513b24"),
        name: "bilbo",
        age: 111
      }
    ]);

    let bedspaces = await Bed.insertMany([
      {
        _id: ObjectId("5c98d89c6bd5fc26a4c2851b"),
        number: 1,
        decks: [
          {
            number: 1,
            tenant: john
          },
          {
            number: 1,
            tenant: jane
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        _id: ObjectId("5c98d89f6bd5fc26a4c28522"),
        number: 2,
        decks: [
          {
            number: 2,
            tenant: bilbo
          },
          {
            number: 3
          }
        ]
      }
    ]);

    await Room.create({ bedspaces });

    // Aggregate

    let results = await Room.aggregate([
      { "$lookup": {
        "from": Bed.collection.name,
        "let": { "bedspaces": "$bedspaces" },
        "pipeline": [
          { "$match": {
            "$expr": { "$in": [ "$_id", "$$bedspaces" ] }
          }},
          { "$lookup": {
            "from": Tenant.collection.name,
            "let": { "tenant": "$decks.tenant" },
            "pipeline": [
              { "$match": {
                "$expr": { "$in": [ "$_id", "$$tenant" ] }
              }}
            ],
            "as": "tenant"
          }},
          { "$addFields": {
            "decks": {
              "$map": {
                "input": "$decks",
                "in": {
                  "$mergeObjects": [
                    "$$this",
                    {
                      "tenant": {
                        "$cond": {
                          "if": {
                            "$eq": [
                              { "$indexOfArray": ["$tenant._id", "$$this.tenant"] },
                              -1
                            ]
                          },
                          "then": null,
                          "else": {

                            "$arrayElemAt": [
                              "$tenant",
                              { "$indexOfArray": ["$tenant._id", "$$this.tenant"]}
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            },
            "tenant": "$$REMOVE"
          }}
        ],
        "as": "bedspaces"
      }}
    ]);

    log(results);

  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  } finally {
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }


})()
```

Returns:

```
Mongoose: tenants.deleteMany({}, {})
Mongoose: beds.deleteMany({}, {})
Mongoose: rooms.deleteMany({}, {})
Mongoose: tenants.insertMany([ { _id: 5c964ae7f5097e3020d1926c, name: 'john doe', age: 11, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5c964b2531bc162fdce64f15, name: 'jane doe', age: 12, __v: 0 }, { _id: 5caa5454494558d863513b24, name: 'bilbo', age: 111, __v: 0 } ], {})
Mongoose: beds.insertMany([ { _id: 5c98d89c6bd5fc26a4c2851b, number: 1, decks: [ { _id: 5caa5af6ed3dce1c3ed72cef, number: 1, tenant: 5c964ae7f5097e3020d1926c }, { _id: 5caa5af6ed3dce1c3ed72cee, number: 1, tenant: 5c964b2531bc162fdce64f15 } ], __v: 0 }, { _id: 5c98d89f6bd5fc26a4c28522, number: 2, decks: [ { _id: 5caa5af6ed3dce1c3ed72cf2, number: 2, tenant: 5caa5454494558d863513b24 }, { _id: 5caa5af6ed3dce1c3ed72cf1, number: 3 } ], __v: 0 } ], {})
Mongoose: rooms.insertOne({ bedspaces: [ ObjectId("5c98d89c6bd5fc26a4c2851b"), ObjectId("5c98d89f6bd5fc26a4c28522") ], _id: ObjectId("5caa5af6ed3dce1c3ed72cf3"), __v: 0 })
Mongoose: rooms.aggregate([ { '$lookup': { from: 'beds', let: { bedspaces: '$bedspaces' }, pipeline: [ { '$match': { '$expr': { '$in': [ '$_id', '$$bedspaces' ] } } }, { '$lookup': { from: 'tenants', let: { tenant: '$decks.tenant' }, pipeline: [ { '$match': { '$expr': { '$in': [ '$_id', '$$tenant' ] } } } ], as: 'tenant' } }, { '$addFields': { decks: { '$map': { input: '$decks', in: { '$mergeObjects': [ '$$this', { tenant: [Object] } ] } } }, tenant: '$$REMOVE' } } ], as: 'bedspaces' } } ], {})
[
  {
    "_id": "5caa5af6ed3dce1c3ed72cf3",
    "bedspaces": [
      {
        "_id": "5c98d89c6bd5fc26a4c2851b",
        "number": 1,
        "decks": [
          {
            "_id": "5caa5af6ed3dce1c3ed72cef",
            "number": 1,
            "tenant": {
              "_id": "5c964ae7f5097e3020d1926c",
              "name": "john doe",
              "age": 11,
              "__v": 0
            }
          },
          {
            "_id": "5caa5af6ed3dce1c3ed72cee",
            "number": 1,
            "tenant": {
              "_id": "5c964b2531bc162fdce64f15",
              "name": "jane doe",
              "age": 12,
              "__v": 0
            }
          }
        ],
        "__v": 0
      },
      {
        "_id": "5c98d89f6bd5fc26a4c28522",
        "number": 2,
        "decks": [
          {
            "_id": "5caa5af6ed3dce1c3ed72cf2",
            "number": 2,
            "tenant": {
              "_id": "5caa5454494558d863513b24",
              "name": "bilbo",
              "age": 111,
              "__v": 0
            }
          },
          {
            "_id": "5caa5af6ed3dce1c3ed72cf1",
            "number": 3,
            "tenant": null
          }
        ],
        "__v": 0
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

Shows the `null` on the second entry of the second entry in the `bedspaces` array as expected.

Comment: you sirr, is a wizard. im just wondering where did you learn this stuff, i have a hard time finding good sources that teaches aggregation, can you share some links??